# How is e.keycode different in safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input is keyup or  keydown i get e.keyCode or e.which. But there is a problem. An example 0 keyCode is 48 in chrome and 96 in safari. How is it possible?

Comment: You should read [**this**](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Comment: idk why but I found this site useful. http://keycode.info/

Comment: i try the keycode.info and i got same result. Safari detect numpad 0 different value then 0. if i use keypress i got same value. But keypress has not e.preventDefault function for killing. Interesting.